# How to create regex that matches only not spaces and not letters?

Tags: java, regex

I have String but very long.

I need to remove all not white spaces and all not letters :

My pattern is :

```
String content=readUrl();
content.replaceAll("(\\S)|(^\\[a-z])", "");
```

And this doesn't work.

Why does my regex replace everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negated character class:

```
(?i)[^\\sa-z]+
```

or better if you want to support all alphabets:

```
[^\\s\\p{L}]+
```

Comment: Thanks but what means (?i)?

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi: This is the case-insensitive modifier. (this is the way to put it directly inside the pattern)

Comment: Thanks. It was big help

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down:

```
content.replaceAll("(\\S)|(^\\[a-z])", "");
```

will replace everything that matches the pattern.  The `|` means a sequence matches the pattern if it matches the part on the left, **or** it matches the part on the right.  The pattern on the left, `(\\S)`, matches every character that isn't white space.  So **every** character that isn't white space will match, and will be eliminated.  I think the part on the right will only match if your string actually begins with the five characters `[a-z]` (since you've told it to treat the `[` literally), so it doesn't really have an effect on the result.  But the result will be that the result will be just white space.

Comment: Great explanation Need to create some tutorials on regex too.